# Retrieve "Pages to Watch" Facebook insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

This Question is tricky, How can I get the **"Pages to Watch"** statistics using the api, at this moment i just reach the total likes using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}?fields=id,name,fan_count&access_token={TOKEN_XXXXXX}
```

[image]

And I like to get something like this.

[image]

but when I try to use other insights query´s data section returns empty, I know that not all the information is public, however I would like to be able to obtain the statistics corresponding to the elements that appear in the section of "Pages to watch" as ***"Total Page Likes,From Last Week,Posts This Week, 
Engagement This Week "***.  Again.. Thanks.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/insights/page_fan_adds?debug=all&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1477612800&access_token={TOKEN_XXXXXX}
```

or for example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/insights/page_engaged_users/day?debug=all&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1477612800&access_token={TOKEN_XXXXXX}
```

[image]

Comment: _"I know that not all the information is public"_ - make that "most of it" … only two page metrics are publicly available, for everything else you need admin access to the page.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, but how to sites like likealyzer, socialbakers etc. do that? just simply add fan page url.. :D .. thanks for your support. really i want to access the information on "Pages to Watch" as seen on the image.

Comment: A lot of those sites use means that are simply not allowed, such as scraping. (But with a big enough user base they could get enough relevant data as well perhaps.)